# how to make component size variation with reactjs and styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

how can I create variation by prop of my button with 'small' or 'medium'?

```
interface Props {
  size?: 'medium' | 'small';
}
```

how can i change the size of the component using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you're using to style your components. For example, if you're using only the `style` prop you could do something like:

```
interface Props {
  size?: 'medium' | 'small'
}

const Component = ({ size }: Props) => {
  return <div style={{ width: size === 'medium' ? 50 : 25 }} />
};
```

Or if you're using CSS, using something like https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames to easily alternate between your classes:

```
interface Props {
  size?: 'medium' | 'small'
}

const Component = ({ size }: Props) => {
  const className = classNames({
    [styles.medium]: size === 'medium',
    [styles.small]: size === 'small',
  });

  return <div className={className} />
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the size as a class and define sizes for each class in your stylesheet.

### Class components

```
import './styles.css';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
        ...
        <div class={this.props.size ? this.props.size : null}>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    }
}
```

### Functional components

```
import './styles.css';

const YourComponent = (props: Props) => {
    ...
    return (
        ...
        <div class={props.size ? props.size : null}>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    );
}
```

`styles.css`

```
.medium {
    width: 100px; // width for medium size
    height: 40px; // height for medium size
}

.small {
    width: 60px; // width for small size
    height: 20px; // height for small size
}
```